# I'm trying to do exponent in c, but this is what is get

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm trying to do a example of exponent en " DEV C++ " compilator and I can't get the output

this is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    double base, exponent, result;

    printf("La base:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&base);
    printf("El exponente:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&exponent);

    result = pow(base, exponent);

    printf("%.1lf^%.1lf = %.21f",  base, exponent, result);

    return 0;       
}
```

and i get this :

[image: exponent]

what could be the problem ?

Sincerilly,
NIN.

Comment: Likely not this, but some compilers , with `printf()`, do not like the `"l"`.  Try `printf("%.1f^%.1f = %.21f",  base, exponent, result);`  ( I suspect the problem is using the wrong .h files)

Comment: I don't see any error in your code and it compiles well with gcc. Your error message seems to indicate that you have a problem with your platform. It points to a line in one of your C library headers, it seems.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with your compiler setup somehow.

Comment: Chux . That doesn't work. It was <math.h> is not found in DEV C++

Comment: Jens and immibis. You 'all are quite right. I download GCC and it work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed us the code from `exponente.c` (I guess), but the error message in the screenshot says:

> error in math.h
>   included from teorema.c

So you should read the error messages very carefully and look for the buggy code in the other file.

Comment: Effectively. Trouble is <math.h> library  is not found.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that I'm using DEV c++, which have lot of errors and libraries which doesn't work.

I download GCC and MinGW for windows.  I compile the same source code in MS-Dos and it worked.

I guess finally I going to use just GCC and I'll forget DEV C++.